# How to fix repeating contents in magento?

Tags: html, magento, caching, block

My magento homepage contents are displayed more than one time. I expect them to appear only once per page.

I tried to put this code to \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php file as a solution:

```
 protected function _construct()

    {
        $this->addData(array(
            'cache_lifetime'    => 900,
            'cache_tags'        => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG),
            'cache_key'            => $this->getCacheKey()
        ));
    } 

public function getCacheKey()
    {
        return $this->getRequest()->getRequestUri().$this->getCacheCurrencyCode();
    }

//retreive current currency code
public function getCacheCurrencyCode()
    {
        return Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    }
```

After this edit whenever I go to my homepage I see some items repeating three times in best seller category as show in following screenshots:

Unexpected Homepage with current errors: 
http://ikelk.lt/i/131171/o_afb38c9691.JPG

How It should Look Ideally (Expected Behavior):
http://ikelk.lt/i/131172/o_568243b784.JPG

Thanks for the help.

Comment: when adding product details to cache you should also add product id/listing type string  in cache tag.

Comment: the issue relates to layouts. You need to check content/layouts of CMS >Pages > home and also all layouts.xml files. Somewhere you specified the same block twice.

Comment: @SatishMantri do you have in mind like this code: 
 array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG . "_" . $this->getProduct()->getId()), if yes it`s the same problem contents are repeating. @Serijo i checked CMS>Pages>home and here are different code line.

Comment: My homepage code:{{block type="catalog/product_list_random" category_id="175" template="catalog/product/geriausipasiulymai.phtml" column_count="2" num_products="6"}}

{{block type="catalog/product_list_random" category_id="176" template="catalog/product/naujienos.phtml" column_count="2" num_products="6"}}

{{block type="catalog/product_list_random" category_id="178" template="catalog/product/populiariausipasiulymai.phtml" column_count="2" num_products="4"}}

Comment: you will need a category ID tag as cache tag.

Comment: @SatishMantri can you give me example ?

Comment: 'cache_tags'        => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG),   replace by 'cache_tags'        => 'list'."_".$catId  something similar to this

Answer (score 0):

Hello i think you check template path hints so you wil get which template calls repeated.

**Goto->Admin->System->Configuration->Current Configuration Scope(select your store)->Advanced(left)->Developer->Debug->Template path hints select yes -> refresh home page**